# Read the color of a Excel Cell & change the tab color of that sheet with the same color

Tags: excel, colors, tabs, cell

I would like help with a code for reading the color of an Excel Cell (whose color changes on conditional statement: ) & change the tab color of that sheet based on that cell color. Any help/Suggestion appreciated. Thanks. 
Here is the conditional statement used in cell:

```
 =WENN(ODER(B2="open";B71="open";B82="open";B107="open");"open";"ok")
```

Here is the code I am using ( I just got some codes online) :

```
Sub GetRGBColor_Fill()
'PURPOSE: Change the Tab Color based on the ActiveCell's Fill Color
    If ActiveCell.Interior.Color = RGB(256, 0, 0) Then
        ActiveSheet.Tab.Color = 256
    ElseIf ActiveCell.Interior.Color = RGB(0, 256, 0) Then
        ActiveSheet.Tab.Color = 3
    Else
        'just some random color
        ActiveSheet.Tab.Color = 100
    End If
```

### End Sub

My intention is that on the first sheet and on 2 other sheets (among 10 sheets), the color of the respective Tab reflects the color of a particular cell, whose color is based on conditional statements, in the respective sheets. Meaning each of the 3 sheets, would have their own colors based on a cell color in the respective sheet. 
I know there are errors in the code, I just want some one to point out what is wrong and how I need to correct it. I am new at this, and thus would appreciate any help.

Comment: Welcome to SO. You should attempt this code yourself first by researching and recording macros, then SO will help with any errors or adapting your code. Users will be less likely to provide answers to your questions if you have not put any effort into attempting to resolve them yourself.

Comment: Sorry, I hadn't posted the code I was using, when I posted the question. I have updated the Post. Apparently the conditional statement part is the one I am difficulty in understanding/implementing in the code written above.

Answer (score 0):

Please, can you try this?

```
Sub setColor(sheet As String)
    With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(sheet)
      If sheet = "Sheet1" Then
        .Tab.Color = .Range("A1").Interior.Color
      ElseIf sheet = "Sheet2" Then
        .Tab.Color = .Range("B5").Interior.Color
      ElseIf sheet = "Sheet3" Then
        .Tab.Color = .Range("F4").Interior.Color
      End If
    End With
End Sub
```

You can call it from your sheets in this way:

```
   Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
      'I guess these are the cells that make the final value [and color] change
      If Target.Column = 2 Then
          If Target.Row = 2 Or Target.Row = 71 Or Target.Row = 82 Or Target.Row = 107 Then setColor ActiveSheet.Name
      End If
   End Sub
```

If the cell is the same on each of your three worksheets it should be simpler because you would not need the `if...elseif...end if` section.

If this does not work try the following:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  setColor ActiveSheet.Name
End Sub
```

but be aware that the `setColor` sub will be called every time a cell on your sheets changes, so depending on the amount of data you are entering it could slow down the entire spreadsheet.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I will try it. Just to give a better/clearer picture. Sheet 1/Table 1 has the code in the Cell B1, and it has the conditional statements as shown in my question. The other sheets/tables have them in their respective sheet cell B3. Apart from Sheet 1, the others have the conditional statements similar (but different from that of Sheet 1) . Meaning they look up different cells with in their own sheets.

Comment: The two Sub's will be in the module file ?
Also shouldn't, in the Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Comment: You will have to change the cells referred to in the setColor subroutine to B1, B3 and again B3 for your sheets. This sub is placed in a module and it is called from each individual worksheet.

Comment: You will find `Worksheet_Change` subroutines in the VBA editor of each individual worksheet. You have to add the code to those of the sheets where you want to have their tab color reflected to that of `B1`, `B3` and `B3`. You will probably have to change the IFs to make them check for a change in the cells of your `=IF(OR(...))` function